# unix - executing output using "cat foo" command

Tags: unix, command, cat

Once I had a file, to see the contents I used cat command, say cat filename, its content was displayed on the terminal, also automatically it typed some random characters on my terminal and `enter` key also got typed and then terminal prompted `command not found`.
  I was wondering whether it is possible to write commands in file and executing those commands using cat command.
  I am not able to get that file again and also searching is not helpful. But I am sure some one over here must know this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a file which had escape sequences that caused the terminal to read the following string as input.  These days that capability tends to not be supported by terminal programs because it's a fairly obvious security issue.

One way this used to be doable was by programming the DEC "answerback" sequence, which the terminal would transmit in response to a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> embedded in the file.

Comment: xterm, gnome-terminal and the linux console have this "feature" up to now. I tested it by catting some large binary file. So I think this "feature" is burried inside the kernel. But what sequence _exactly_ triggers this ... I don't know.

Comment: Still?  That is bad.  (But only the Linux console one is in the kernel; the others, it is part of those programs.)  I could not tell you offhand what the sequence is that's triggering it; historically there were a number of possibilities for different terminals.

Comment: *All* terminals (even xterm & co) use the kernel for TTY handling - either in the form of "pseudo terminals" (xterm & co) or "virtual consoles". And I guess that's the culprit here.

Comment: But ptys do not have built in emulation of any kind, and this is controlled by the emulation.

Comment: Good point. So it seems the VC on one hand and xterm & Co on the other hand try to stay compatible with each other with independent code. :-)

Comment: Yes and no; both (and `gnome-terminal`) have similar emulation goals (based on the DEC VT220 series terminals as standardizeded by ANSI X3.64), implemented differently — this emulation is not part of the tty driver.  `xterm` also has VT52 and Tektronix 4014 emulation modes, which the Linux console and `gnome-terminal` do not.

Comment: so any conclusion ? How can we get those sequences ? @A.H. Can you provide that binary file or reach to the minimum piece of file which is able to produce the sequence

Comment: @Peeyush: I've used `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres` as a test binary. But I have no intention to trim the 5.5M down to find the actual codes.

Comment: You can pore through `ctlseqs.ms` (http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) to see if you can find it.